# Accessing ref values from composable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, ref, vue-reactivity, composable

Here is my Vue3 app code:

```js
<template>
  {{ names_data }}
</template>

<script>
import getData from "./composables/getData"

export default {
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    var filenames = ["test1.json", "test2.json"];
    const { names_data, error, load_data } = getData(
      filenames
    );
    load_data();
    console.log("names", names_data)

    console.log("error", error)

    return { names_data };
  },
};
</script>
```

The imported composable function is the following:

```js
import { ref } from "@vue/runtime-core";

const getData = (filenames) => {
  const names_data = ref([])
  const error = ref(null)

  const load_data = async () => {
    try {
      var promises = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
        var filename = filenames[i]
        promises.push(
          fetch(`data/${filename}`).then(
            (res) => (res.ok && res.json()) || Promise.reject(res)
          )
        );
      }
      const data = await Promise.all(promises);
      names_data.value = data
    } catch (err) {
      error.value = err.message;
      console.log(error.value);
    }
  };
  return { names_data, error, load_data }
};

export default getData
```

and the data files contain the following:

**test1.json**

```json
{
  "members": {
    "0": "Alice",
    "1": "Bob",
    "2": "Charlie"
  }
}
```

**test2.json**

```json
{
  "members": {
    "0": "David",
    "1": "Elizabeth",
    "2": "Fred"
  }
}
```

This all works: I can see the `names_data` from the template showing on screen. However in the console the `names_data` appears as follows:

> RefImpl {_shallow: false, dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, _rawValue: Array(0), _value: Proxy}
> dep: Set(1) {ReactiveEffect}
> __v_isRef: true
> _rawValue: (2) [{…}, {…}]
> _shallow: false
> _value: Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}}
> value: (...)
> [[Prototype]]: Object

I want to be able to access the values in `names_data` for further processing, like putting them in a table, but when I do `console.log(names_data.value)` in the App I get a Proxy object to an empty array.
I think the `names_data` object loses reactivity somehow, as it is not updated when `load_data()` is called. But it clearly is reactive in the template. So I'm confused about what is going on here.

How can I access the value of the ref to process it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. Without using reactivity this would result in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) popular race condition. The point of using reactivity is that values are reactive and can be composed in other places through composition API.

In this case it's unnecessary to wait for `load_data` to complete in `setup` body. It's supposed to be accessed at the time when a value is available:

```
const { names_data, error, load_data } = getData(...);
load_data();
watch(names_data, data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Vue and Javascript so the link is helpful.

Comment: I have a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70247984/accessing-ref-values-from-composable-part-2

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up answer to Estus Flask's accepted answer:

If I make `names_data` a dictionary instead of a list, i.e. by doing

```
...
names_data = ref({})
...
...
    const data = await Promise.all(promises);
    for (let ind=0; ind<data.length; ind++) {
      let filename = filenames[ind]
      names_data.value[filename] = data[ind]
    }
...
```

then `watch()` no longer works. It has to be replaced in the `setup()` by `watchEffect()` as follows:

```
    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log("updated data", names_data.value)
    })
```