# Accessing ref values from composable (part 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

This is a follow-on question from my previous question here:
[Accessing ref values from composable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185066/accessing-ref-values-from-composable/70198603#70198603)

Here is my App code:

```
<template>
  {{ reversed_names }}
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watchEffect } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import getData from "./composables/getData";
import reverseNames from "./composables/reverseNames";

export default {
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    var filenames = ["test1.json", "test2.json"];
    const { names_data, error, load_data } = getData(filenames);
    load_data();

    const reversed_names = ref({});

    watchEffect(() => {
      const reversed_names = reverseNames(names_data.value);
      console.log("revnames inside watchEffect", reversed_names.value);
    });
    console.log("revnames outside watchEffect", reversed_names);

    return { names_data, reversed_names };
  },
};
</script>
```

and here is the `reverseNames` function:

```
import { ref } from "@vue/runtime-core";

const reverseNames = (names_data) => {
  const reverse_names = ref({})
  var filenames = Object.keys(names_data)
  for (let f in filenames) {
    var filename = filenames[f]
    reverse_names.value[filename] = {}
    var members = names_data[filename]["members"]
    for (let n in members) {
      let name = members[n];
      var reverseName = name.split("").reverse().join("");
      reverse_names.value[filename][name] = reverseName
    }
  }
  return reverse_names
};

export default reverseNames
```

The `watchEffect` is there so I can use `names_data` once the data is loaded from a file (see linked question above).
The code works fine up to the call to `reverseNames`.
`names_data.value` contains the following:

```
{ "test1.json": 
    { "members": 
        { "0": "Alice", 
          "1": "Bob", 
          "2": "Charlie" 
        } 
    }, 
  "test2.json": 
    { "members": 
        { "0": "David", 
          "1": "Elizabeth", 
          "2": "Fred" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Here's the confusing part:

Inside the `watchEffect` function, the console shows the correct return dictionary from the function.
However, outside the `watchEffect` function, the console just shows the empty `ref({})` defined before the `watchEffect()` call.

It is the empty dictionary that is returned by `setup()` and displayed in the template.

How can I get the `setup()` to return the `reversed_names` from inside the `watchEffect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const reversed_names` outside and inside `watchEffect` function scope are different, unrelated variables. `reversed_names` inside function scope shadows another one from parent scope.

A ref is a pattern that makes use of that in JavaScript objects are passed by reference, not by value. This means that it's a ref and not a value that needs to be passed in every place that needs to preserve reactivity and be aware of that it's used in the context of Vue application. A variable that holds a ref should be never reassigned, instead `value` property needs to be reassigned.

`reverseNames` is not general purpose helper function but is specific to Vue, so can accept a ref. `reverse_names` doesn't serve a good purpose because it's not passed anywhere and therefore doesn't benefit from using ref pattern. It could be:

```
const reverseNames = (namesDataRef) => {
  const reverse_names = {} // not a ref
  var filenames = Object.keys(namesDataRef.value)
    reverse_names[filename] = {}
      ...
      reverse_names[filename][name] = reverseName
    }
  }

  namesDataRef.value = reverse_names;
  // doesn't need to return anything because it uses refs
}
```

and

```
const reversed_names = ref({});

watchEffect(() => {
  reverseNames(reversed_names);
  console.log("revnames inside watchEffect", reversed_names.value);
});
```

This is an antipattern. This would make sense if `reverseNames` were using asynchronous side effects or anything that could trigger changes that cannot be tracked during `reverseNames` call, similarly to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185066/accessing-ref-values-from-composable/). But it's synchronous and doesn't affect anything but a single ref, so there are no reasons for it to use reactivity. Instead, reactivity could be lifted to a caller:

```
const reverseNames = (namesData) => {
  const reverse_names = {} // not a ref
  ...
  return reverse_names
}
```

and

```
const reversed_names = ref({});

watchEffect(() => {
  reversed_names.value = reverseNames(names_data.value);
  console.log("revnames inside watchEffect", reversed_names.value);
});
```

Without a side effect (`console.log`), there would be no need for `watchEffect`, it could be a computed ref:

```
const reversed_names = computed(() => reverseNames(names_data.value));
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks again for another helpful answer.